# Not getting any chunk.js/module.js with lazy routes Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've setup my application with lazy routes. Everything works fine but I'm not getting any chunk.js/module.js in my network tab.

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./main/pages/home/home.module').then(m => HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'c',
    loadChildren: () => import('./main/pages/category/category.module').then(m => CategoryModule)
  }
];
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabled'
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then I include the routing module in my app.module.
Finally in my components modules I set up a routerChild like this.

**home.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

Routes load up just fine, but I can't see any new chunk getting created.
Also, I'm using Angular Universal I don't know if that's messing things up.

Comment: So the HomeComponent is part of two modules ? 
Because i see that it is defined in app.module (declarations array) and in routing you ask for HomeModule to return it.
It is normal that you see no chunks.

Comment: I didn't put any code of the app.module. The last one is the HomeComponent module.